# Fourier series of a piecewise continuous (constant) function. Is my solution correct?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

Given the function
$$
 \phi(x)
=\begin{cases}
 1 & 0<x\leq 1 \\
2 & 1<x \leq 2 \\
3 & 2<x \leq 3 \\
4 & 3<x \leq 4
\end{cases}
$$

First, I extended $\phi$ to a periodic function on $[-4, 4]$ such that $\phi(x+4) = \phi(x)$ for all $x \in [-4, 0]$.

(a) To what values does the Fourier series converge at $x=0, 1, 4, 7.4, 40$?

SOLUTION: At $x=0, 4, 40$, the Fourier series converges to $\frac{\phi(0+) + \phi(0-)}{2} = \frac{1+4}{2} = 2.5$.
At $x=7.4$, the furrier series converges to $\phi(7.4 \bmod{4}) = \phi(3.4) = 4$. Finally, at $x=1$, the series converges to $\frac{1+2}{2} = 1.5$.

(b) Does the Fourier series converge uniformly to $\phi$?

SOLUTION: No, since it does not converge to $\phi$ point-wise.

(c) Find $a_0$.

SOLUTION:
$$
 a_0 = \frac{1}{4}\int_{-4}^4 \phi(x)\cos(0)\,\mathrm{d}{x} = \frac{1}{4}(20) = 5
$$

Comment: There is no obvious reason why you would extend it to a periodic function on $[-4,4]$, given that the Fourier series of the original function will converge to a periodic extension $\tilde{\phi}$, satisfying $\tilde{\phi}(x+4)=\tilde{\phi}(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, anyway. Your integration is the same over multiples of the interval, so

$$a_n = \frac{2}{4-0} \int_0^4 \phi(x)\,dx
= \frac{1}{2} (1+2+3+4) = 5$$
but yeah besides that note it's fine.

Comment: One issue with directly extending prior to computing the Fourier series is that it is not unique. You could have extended the function so that it satisfies $\phi(-x)=\phi(x)$ on $[-4,4]$. The Fourier series would agree on $(0,4]$ except at jump discontinuities. In that case you would actually find $\frac{\tilde{\phi}(0^+)+\tilde{\phi}(0^-)}{2} = 1$ and $\frac{\tilde{\phi}(4^+)+\tilde{\phi}(4^-)}{2} = 4$